# Load a json url from Webclient

Tags: c#

I want to get data from this json url.

https://viabilita.autostrade.it/traffico-fasce-orarie-cantieri-liguria/all2.json

This data is used from this page:

https://viabilita.autostrade.it/traffico-fasce-orarie-cantieri-liguria/index.html

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://viabilita.autostrade.it/traffico-fasce-orarie-cantieri-liguria/all2.json");

    // Now parse with JSON.Net
}
```

If I try to get from webclient I get a totally different string from when I use the browser to get it.

Is perhaps the "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" that cause this? Is it some other header to add to my request?

Thank you

Comment: What is this "totally different string" you get? I did a simple curl command in my terminal and it seems to be the same json that I get in the browser.

Comment: I tried with curl command and I get the right string. From webclient I get an Hml source like '''<!doctype html>
<html lang="it-IT">

<head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Autostrade per l'Italia</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="Description" content="Autostrade per l'Italia">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">'''

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default `HttpClient` won't send any User-Agent and this will make quite a few sites suspious. I tried the same request without setting an User-Agent header and it returned an HTML document instead.

So you need to add a `User-Agent` header and it will probably work (and to be a good sport, add a user-agent that identifies your application).

```cs
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "MyApp/1.0");
    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://viabilita.autostrade.it/traffico-fasce-orarie-cantieri-liguria/all2.json");

    // Now parse with JSON.Net
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem then you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark under the voting controls.